# NFC Tag Reading App. Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, sigabrt

I'm getting this error when I hit the scan button on my app, and I don't know how to solve it:

> NFC Tag Reading App. Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Xcode shows no errors at all and it crashes when I hit the Scan button, everything else works fine.

```
import UIKit
import CoreNFC

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let reuseIdentifier = "reuseIdentifier"
    var detectedMessages = [NFCNDEFMessage]()
    var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?

    // MARK: - IB-Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: - ViewDidLoad Method

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }

    // MARK: - ViewDidAppear Method

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }

    // MARK: - Scan Button Pressed

    @IBAction func beginScanning(_ sender: UIButton) {
        session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
        session?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near the item to learn more about it."
        session?.begin()
    }


    // MARK: - User Information Button Pressed

    @IBAction func userInformationButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }

    // MARK: - Log Out Button Pressed

    @IBAction func logOutButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }

    // MARK: - NFC ReaderSession Delegates

    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        // Check the invalidation reason from the returned error.
        if let readerError = error as? NFCReaderError {
            // Show an alert when the invalidation reason is not because of a success read
            // during a single tag read mode, or user canceled a multi-tag read mode session
            // from the UI or programmatically using the invalidate method call.
            if (readerError.code != .readerSessionInvalidationErrorFirstNDEFTagRead)
                && (readerError.code != .readerSessionInvalidationErrorUserCanceled) {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(
                    title: "Session Invalidated",
                    message: error.localizedDescription,
                    preferredStyle: .alert
                )
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }

        // A new session instance is required to read new tags.
        self.session = nil
    }

    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Process detected NFCNDEFMessage objects.
            self.detectedMessages.append(contentsOf: messages)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - addMessage(fromUserActivity:)

    func addMessage(fromUserActivity message: NFCNDEFMessage) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.detectedMessages.append(message)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

extension HomeViewController {

    // MARK: - Table View Functions

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return detectedMessages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        let message = detectedMessages[indexPath.row]
        let unit = message.records.count == 1 ? " Payload" : " Payloads"
        cell.textLabel?.text = message.records.count.description + unit

        return cell
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
            let payloadsTableViewController = segue.destination as? PayloadsTableViewController else {
                return
        }
        payloadsTableViewController.payloads = detectedMessages[indexPath.row].records
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you add this `<key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key> <string>NFC tag to read NDEF messages into the application</string>` to your info.plist And turn on the  NFC in capabilities?

Comment: Yes, I did that already and nothing :(